# Web.py - AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'application'

Tags: python, google-app-engine, web.py

I use web.py write small helloworld site,but when I run `python code.py` I get an error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "E:\Python25\webpy\web\mysite.py", line 1, in <module>
    import web   File "E:\Python25\webpy\web\web.py", line 4, in <module>
    app = web.application(urls, globals()) AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'application'
```

Here is my code(paste from web.py's tutorials):

```
import web

urls = ( '/','Index',
)

class Index:
  def GET(self):
    return "Hello,world!"

app=web.application(urls,globals())

if __name__=="__main__":
  app.run(
```

P.S:The web.py version is 0.35.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are runing into name collisions.  You named your package web, and are trying to import a module web.

I am assuming this is in a package?

`\webpy\web\mysite.py`

If so when you do `import web` you are importing *your* package not the actual web.py.  Rename it, or reorder your pythonpath.

Comment: you mean my web module was conflict with the Web.py?But I can't find my web.py:(

Comment: Do you have a \_\_init\_\_.py in webpy\web\ ?

Comment: Yes,I have a __init__.py in webpy\web\

Comment: See above, its not importing the **real** web.py

Comment: If you first started by calling your file `web.py`, rather than `code.py` as in the Python tutorial, you might also have a `web.pyc` "byte code" file created in the folder where you are coding. After discovering the name collision, make sure you also delete the `web.pyc` file.

Comment: @sameers, your comment should be answer, it was the culprit in my case

Answer (score 1):

This worked in my case: in the **app.yaml** file, replace

```
- url: /.*
  script: test.application
```

for this,

```
- url: /.*
  script: test.app
```

This solve the name conflict.

Answer (score 1):

Per recommendation from a user above, I have turned my comment into an answer to improve its visibility:

If you first started by calling your file `web.py`, rather than `code.py` as in the Python tutorial, you might also have a `web.pyc` "byte code" file created in the folder where you are coding. After discovering the name collision, make sure you also delete the `web.pyc` file.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the current directory has web.py, or web.pyc files